# Accessing password from a file in puppet for use in exec

Tags: puppet

I want to run a command in open source puppet to activate a Unity3D license, but I don't want the serial or the password in my git repo:

```
exec { 'license-unity': 
  command => '/opt/Unity/Editor/Unity -batchmode -nographics -serial A1-ABCD-1234-ETC -username my.user@a.b.ca -password myPassword -quit'
  subscribe   => Package['UnityEditor'],
  refreshonly => true,
}
```

How can I read the serial# and the password from a file (either on the puppetserver or on the node) and substitute it in the command?

For example, if I had a file on the puppet server called `.secret` owned by root and perms 400. How do I read the content into a variable for use in the puppet manifest?

Comment: What version of Puppet?

Comment: Latest open source

Comment: How about Hiera + eyaml ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two standard ways to achieve this given the route you prefer:

1. Use the `file` function. This is for masterless Puppet or the file is hosted on the Puppet Master.

   ```
   # using the module path instead of the absolute path would end up storing your secret in git, which is what you are trying to avoid
   $password = file('/absolute/path/to/.secret')

   exec { 'license-unity': 
     command     => "/opt/Unity/Editor/Unity -batchmode -nographics -serial A1-ABCD-1234-ETC -username my.user@a.b.ca -password $password -quit"
     subscribe   => Package['UnityEditor'],
     refreshonly => true,
   }
   ```

   Doc: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/function.html#file

   Corollary: If you need to do some kind of parsing on the file, such as if it is more than a text file with the password inside, then you can use a custom function with the modern Ruby API. https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/functions_ruby_overview.html. Let me know if this is the case.
2. Use a custom fact. This is for storing the file on the client in a Master/Client setup. Using an external fact would also end up storing the secret in git, which would present the problem you are attempting to avoid.

   ```
   # module/lib/facter/password.rb
   Facter.add(:password) do
     setcode do
       File.read('/absolute/path/to/.secret')
     end
   end

   # manifest.pp
   exec { 'license-unity': 
     command     => "/opt/Unity/Editor/Unity -batchmode -nographics -serial A1-ABCD-1234-ETC -username my.user@a.b.ca -password $password -quit"
     subscribe   => Package['UnityEditor'],
     refreshonly => true,
   }
   ```

   Doc: https://puppet.com/docs/facter/3.9/custom_facts.html#configuring-facts

   Corollary: If you need to do some kind of parsing on the file, such as if it is more than a text file with the password inside, then you can use native Ruby classes and methods for that (i.e. `JSON.parse` or `YAML.load_file` if the file is in those formats).

Notable alternatives to the method you are pursuing include using Puppet to retrieve from a secrets management software, such as Vault, or using encryption/decryption algorithms, such as AES-256, to store the encrypted file in your SCM and then decrypt it during catalog compilation.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that with recent Puppet, both of these approaches will end up recording the password in PuppetDB.  The OP didn't say anything about that, so maybe it's OK, but it would suck to be caught by surprise by something like that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Very good point, in which case secrets management would probably be the best choice if that is an issue. The encryption/decrpytion function would store it there too.